Evaluating an integral that's almost a Gaussian convolution -- but with a variable standard deviation
I'm trying to find fast ways to evaluate the following integral defined over points $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$:
$$\Phi(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2(\mathbf{x})}\int d^2y\, \exp\left(-\frac{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|^2}{2\sigma^2(\mathbf{x})}\right)\phi(\mathbf{y}).$$
Here $\phi(\mathbf{x})$ is a smooth function. This almost looks like a Gaussian convolution, except for the fact that the standard deviation $\sigma(\mathbf{x})$ depends on the coordinate $\mathbf{x}$. Assume that $\sigma(\mathbf{x})$ is also a smooth function. If the integral were a proper convolution, I could've used the Fourier convolution theorem and fast-Fourier techniques to evaluate it.
One possibility is to expand $\sigma(\mathbf{x})$ in the form $\sigma(\mathbf{x}) = \sigma_0 + \sigma_1(\mathbf{x}) + \sigma_2(\mathbf{x}) + \ldots$ and compute the resulting $\sigma_i(\mathbf{x})$-dependent integrals one by one.  But I was
wondering if there are better methods.

Hmm. For fixed $x$ this integral in $y$ is an inner product of two functions $( \phi(y)$ and a Gaussian in $y$) that can be formally expressed by Parseval's Identity as the inner product of their respective Fourier transforms. The transformed representation of the integral in the frequency domain is
$$\Phi(x)= \int \int  \hat \phi(\xi) e^{- i \xi \cdot x} e^{-\sigma(x)^2 \xi^2} d\xi$$ which perhaps you can  evaluate approximately by the fast Fourier transform.
FWIW. Another speculative proposal:
Note first that $$\Phi(\vec x)= \int\int _{\vec u}  e^{- |\vec u|^2} \phi( \vec x+\sigma(x) \vec u) du$$
The mass of the Gaussian lies mostly within a few standard deviations in the $\vec u$ plane. If in such a region you can approximate $\phi( \vec x+\sigma(x) \vec u)$ by a polynomial in $u$ whose coefficients depend on $x$, and then express that polynomial  as a sum of Hermite polynomials $\sum_k c_k(x)H_k(u)$, then the integral assumes the form of an inner product  $< e^{-|u|^2/2},e^{-|u|^2/2} \sum_k c_k(x)H_k(u)>$ of two quantities that have been expanded in an orthogonal basis ( Hermite functions).

Yes, this is a way to compute the integral, but it's not fast.  For each $x$, you'll have to do a 2D integral, which takes $\mathcal{O}(N\log N)$ steps using FFT, and you need to do this for $N^2$ points.  Better than brute forcing, but still slow for practical purposes.
